# Find change of basis matrix for $P_2(R)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

> Let T be the linear mapping on $P_2(R)$ (it is a set of polynomial to the $2^{nd}$ power) defined by $T(f(x))=f(x)+(x+1) f'(x)$, let $\beta$ be the standard ordered basis for $P_2(R)$, and let $A=[T]_{\beta}$. Find matrix A

$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$.

I know the standard basis $\beta$ is {$1,x,x^2$} and I know A is the matrix made of coordinate vectors of $\beta$. I am not quite sure how they get to the matrix A.

My thoughts are we can let $f(x)=x^2+x+1$, then T(f(x))=$3x^2+4x+2$
And I know the formula $[T]_{\beta}$=$A [T]_\beta'$. But I still don't see how the operation goes.

Comment: Applied the given mapping to the basis elements and put the coefficients into columns.

Comment: @Berci Can you be more specific? it still doesn't click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a 'change of base' matrix: note that we are given only one basis (the standard one: $\beta=(1,x,x^2)$).

Instead, it's simply the matrix $A$ of the transformation $T$ in the basis $\beta$, that satisfies for all $f\in P_2(\Bbb R)$
$$[T(f)]_\beta \ =\ A\cdot [f]_\beta$$
If you apply this to the $i$th basis vector $e_i$, on the right hand side you simply get the $i$th column of $A$, which thus should consist of the $\beta$-coordinates of $T(e_i)$.

In the example we have 
$$T(1)=1+(x+1)\cdot 0=1\\
T(x)=x+(x+1)\cdot 1=1+2x\\
T(x^2) =x^2 +(x+1)\cdot(2x)=2x+3x^2$$
and these coefficients are put into the columns of $A$.

Comment: I was in the loop and couldn't get out of that... Thanks alot!